# How to prove the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ equals $0$?

Tags: limits, analysis

I've got $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$

So It seems that its going to be zero, since the only values $(-1)^{n+1}$ can be are 1 and -1. Still I don't know if that's enough justification.

Comment: It can be solved by using the sandwich theorem!!!

Comment: Use that $$(-1)^{x+1}$$ is bounded by $$-1\le (-1)^{x+1}\le 1$$

Comment: How is $(-1)^{x+1}$ defined for non-integer values of $x$?

Comment: Probably you mean $x$ is an integer here and in that case it is conventional to use symbol $n$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Corrected, now it shows only integers (n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know $(-1)^n$ is either $1$ or $-1$, you can apply the Squeeze Theorem.
$$-1 \leq (-1)^{n+1} \leq 1$$
$$\frac{-1}{n} \leq \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{-1}{n} \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}$$
Both left and right limits tend to $0$ obviously.
$$0^- \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \leq 0^+$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-0\right|=\left|\frac1{n}-0\right|=\frac1n.$$

Answer (score 0):

First case
if $n=2k$ then 
$$
\\\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{-1}{2k}=0
$$
Second case
if $n=2k+1$ then
$$
\\\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{2k+1}=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{-1}{n} \leq \frac{-1^{n+1}}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

It's easy to see see where the limits on outside go.